# Can't start Git Gui

Tags: git, user-interface

I created a repository on github and transferred it to my computer, but when I try to run git gui through git bash, it gives this error. I've tried reinstalling git but it didn't work. Also created another repository and saw the same error.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mWh.png)

Comment: How exactly do You run git gui?

Comment: Are You able to fetch, pull, commit, push changes with git bash?

Comment: Yes, I can. I run git gui from git bash  $ git gui&